# .htaccess internal server error 500

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error

I have an .htaccess file. The content is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule (.*\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css|swf))$ webroot/img_handler.php?arg=$1 [L] 
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# test 5

# disable directory browsing -IMPORTANT, do NOT remove.
Options -Indexes

# protect the htaccess file
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off


# protect php.ini
<files *.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

and this is cause an internal server error, what's the problem?

thx:
pixeles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

The rewrite engine loops until the URI stops changing, and the `(.*)` pattern is matching *everything*, including `webroot/whatever`. Try adding a condition in front of it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webroot
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```